# error controller ctrlreg the controller with the name "chatCtrl" is not registered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular. Maybe I'm dense, but not sure anyone else is seeing the same problem I'm having despite my checks for the prescribed naming errors. I've used the convention Ctrl as shorthand for controller.

My Chat Controller `ChatCtrl.js` is as follows

```
    angular.module("blocChat")
      .controller("ChatCtrl", function($scope, Message, Room) {
         $scope.roomName
         $scope.rooms = Room.all
         $scope.goToRoom = function(room) {
           $scope.selectedRoom = room
           console.log($scope.selectedRoom)
           $scope.messages = Message.getByRoomId($scope.selectedRoom.id)
         }
         $scope.message = function() {
         }
       });
```

My `Index.html` is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="blocChat">
    <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Bloc Chat Project</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,700,300">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/landing.css"> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/home.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/room.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="home" ng-controller="ChatCtrl">
      <!-- <ng-include src="'/templates/home.html'"></ng-include> -->
      <h1>Bloc Chat</h1>
      <h2>{{ roomName }}</h2>
      <ul><li ng-repeat="room in rooms"><a ng-click="goToRoom(room)">{{ room.name }}</a></li></ul>
      <h1>Room: {{ selectedRoom.name }}<h1>
        <h2>Room Html<h2>
        <div><li ng-repeat="message in messages"> {{ message.text }} </li></div>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <!-- ui's -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
      <!-- firebase -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.6/firebase.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
      <!-- css -->
      <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.css"></script> -->
      <!-- app scripts -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-cookies.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/controllers/ChatCtrl.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/controllers/HomeCtrl.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/controllers/RoomCtrl.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/controllers/UsernameCtrl.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/factory/Message.js"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/factory/Room.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This happened around the time I created the following file, but I've been advised this is probably just coincidence, `UsernameCtrl.js`:

```
    angular.module("blocChat", ['ui.bootstrap'])
      .controller("UsernameCtrl", function($scope, $uibModal) {
        $uibModal.open({
          controller: "ModalCtrl",
          templateUrl: "/templates/username.html"
        })
      })
      .controller("ModalCtrl", function($uibModalInstance, $scope) {
        $scope.user = {
          username: "John",
          password: "test"
        }
      })
      .run(function($uibModal) {
        $uibModal.open({
          controller: "ModalCtrl",
          templateUrl: "/templates/username.html"
        })
      })
```

My code in `app.js`:

```
    angular
      .module('blocChat', ['firebase', 'ui.bootstrap'])
      .config(function($locationProvider) {
        var config = {
          apiKey: // Firebase API key
          authDomain:// Firebase Auth domain ("*.firebaseapp.com")
          databaseURL: // Firebase Database URL("https://*.firebaseio.com")
          storageBucket: "bloc-chat-117d5.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "324260113714"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
      })
```

my overall code is here: https://github.com/seanbode/bloc-chat
I've tried it with and without the `[]` in `ChatCtrl.js` when I call `angular.module("blocChat")`. I appreciate any advice you can give me as I understand I have a lot to learn in the ways of coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring the same module twice

Without the second argument `anguler.module('moduleName')` is a getter. But with the dependency injection argument it is a setter.

Change:

```
angular.module("blocChat", [])
```

To

```
angular.module("blocChat")
```

Or move the dependency injection to this declaration since order of script loading has this one loading first

Comment: I originally tried it without the "[]" as mentioned in the last part of my post. Thank you for bringing this error to my attention I'll clarify it in the original post to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Notice the order of scripts loading though. Make sure setter precedes getter

Comment: Yes..you need it for `ui.bootstrap` but you need to make sure the script loading order has your setter file before any getter for that module

Comment: As mentioned in the answer ... the one and only one for a specific module that has the dependency injection array is the one that sets the module (registers it) ... the ones without the injection array are references to that existing module (getter). But can't get until you set so script loading order will matter

Comment: I believe this great advice solved my problem. The fact I called `ui.bootstrap` in the `UsernameCtrl.js` meant that script needed to precede `chatCtrl.js` in the order since that's where I was calling the module.

Comment: Should probably be setting it in `app.js` but not sure what you have in there